# MySqlConnection' is ambiguous in the namespace 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient [Visual Basic -VS2008]

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to make a connection to a database [MySql] on localhost but I have a problem ....

This is the code : (it's a class called ConnectDateBase.vb...)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class ConnectDateBase

    Public Class MySQLConnect
        Public db_con As New MySqlConnection
        Private Sub connect()
            Dim dbname As String = "DBNAME"
            Dim dbhost As String = "localhost"
            Dim user As String = "root"
            Dim pass As String = "DBPASSWORD"


            If Not db_con Is Nothing Then db_con.Close()
            db_con.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", dbhost, user, pass, dbname)

            Try
                db_con.Open()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Database Error:[" & ex.Message & "]")
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
```

This is my problem: 
Error List ->

> 1. MySqlConnection' is ambiguous in the namespace 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient
> 2. MySqlException' is ambiguous in the namespace 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient
>      [Errors have identical type]

I tried to add reference but i don't know what reference to add...( Mysql.web or Mysql.data) both failed ...
As OS I'm using : windows xp sp3 with NET Framework 3.5 and MySql Connector NET 6.8.3 installed.
Know anyone how to fix this (logical error ) please ...

Comment: try to remove all references related to MySql, then add reference only to Mysql.data.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that compiler get confused because there are several assembly references containing same namespace. Try to remove all references related to MySql, then add reference only to `Mysql.data.dll`.